# Simple HTML DOM get attribute from <div> tag

Tags: web-scraping, simple-html-dom

i am trying to get the 'tel' attribute of  but cant get it.

```
<div class="horizontal-center" ng-class="classActive()" ng-click="clicked($event)" id="7076213" account-id="536423" user-id="651772" event-label="listing-detail" event-action="phone-number-viewed-in-sideways" tel="8503128272" action-type="DetailPhone">
```

i was trying with these codes.
1.

```
foreach ($html1->find('div.horizontal-center') as $phone) {
 echo   $ilanlar['phone'] = $phone->{'tel'};
}
```

2.

```
foreach ($html1->find('div.horizontal-center') as $phone) {
 echo   $ilanlar['phone'] = $phone->getattribute('tel');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');


$html1 = str_get_html('<div class="horizontal-center" ng-class="classActive()" ng-click="clicked($event)" id="7076213" account-id="536423" user-id="651772" event-label="listing-detail" event-action="phone-number-viewed-in-sideways" tel="8503128272" action-type="DetailPhone">');

foreach ($html1->find('div.horizontal-center') as $phone) {
    echo $ilanlar['phone'] = $phone->{'tel'};
}

echo '<br>'; 

foreach ($html1->find('div.horizontal-center') as $phone) {
    echo $ilanlar['phone'] = $phone->getattribute('tel');
}
```

Works fine for me. Output is:

```
8503128272<br>8503128272
```